# A variabel on Method "onOptionsItemSelected" not update in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment like the following, I know how to communicate between fragments by making parameters and attaching them to the Bundle argument. in this case the fragment will call a new fragment and will overwrite the old display fragment. Then i need to pass value between fragment to new fragment. When I press the share menu on `Actionbar` button I want the url share to match the current one Its works if i console it with log, but still old value

```
public class ReadingFragment extends Fragment implements
        ReadFragView,
        RelatedNewsAdapter.RelatedNewsCallback {

    private static final String ARG_GUID = "ARG_GUID";
    public static final String ARG_BOOKMARK = "ARG_BOOKMARK";
    public static final String ARG_URLSHARE = "ARG_URLSHARE";

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    private String guidData;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private ReadFragPresenter readFragPresenter;

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    private String urlForSharing;
    private Bookmark bookmark;

    public ReadingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static ReadingFragment newInstance(String guid, Bookmark bookmark, String urlShare) {
        ReadingFragment fragment = new ReadingFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_GUID, guid);
        if(bookmark != null){
            args.putSerializable(ARG_BOOKMARK, bookmark);
        }
        if(urlShare != null){
            // --- THIS LINE IS WORKING --- //
            args.putString(ARG_URLSHARE, urlShare);
        }
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        readFragPresenter = new ReadFragPresenterImpl(this, getActivity().getApplication());
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            guidData = getArguments().getString(ARG_GUID);
            bookmark = (Bookmark) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_BOOKMARK);
            // --- THIS LINE IS WORKING TOO, VALUE URLFORSHARING IS CORRECT ---
            urlForSharing = getArguments().getString(ARG_URLSHARE);
            Timber.d("OnCreate urlShare %s", urlForSharing);

        }
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reading, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_reading, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.share:
                // ---THIS IS THE PROBLEM, THIS LINE IS STILL OLD VALUE --- //
                Timber.d("urlSharing selected %s", urlForSharing);
                // --- THIS IS THE PROBLEM -----//
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""+ DeviceUtil.getApplicationName(getContext()));
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlForSharing);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via"));
                return true;

            case R.id.bookmark:
                Timber.d("select item  %s", bookmark.toString());
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void resultLoadSelectedNews(boolean isSuccess, MotherArticle motherArticle) {

        if(isSuccess){
            Article article = motherArticle.getArticles().get(0);
            //RELATED NEWS
            RelatedNewsAdapter relatedNewsAdapter = new RelatedNewsAdapter(getContext(),
                    motherArticle.getRelates(), this);
            recycleRelatedNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            recycleRelatedNews.setAdapter(relatedNewsAdapter);

            // FOR SHARING (FIRST OPENING)
            urlForSharing = article.getMoreLink();

            // FOR BOOKMARK (FIRST OPENING)
            bookmark = new Bookmark();
            bookmark.setTitle(article.getHeadLine());
            Timber.d("isi bookmark -> %s", bookmark.toString());

        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClick(Related related) {

        bookmark = new Bookmark();
        bookmark.setTitle(related.getTitle());

        // --- VALUE URLSHARE IS UPDATED HERE--//
        String urlShare = related.getLink();
        Timber.d("urlShared %s", urlShare);

        ReadingFragment fragment = ReadingFragment.newInstance(related.getGuid(), bookmark, urlShare);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.add(R.id.dynamic_fragment_frame, fragment, "FRAGMENT_"+related.getGuid());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

the url on `onOptionsItemSelected` is still the old url, even though it should have been replaced by the new url the url above is still the old url, even though it should have been replaced by the new url which I have updated through the Bundle argument.

Comment: `urlForSharing` is set from bundle for first time . Its only getting reset inside `resultLoadSelectedNews` . If `resultLoadSelectedNews` will never get called it won't reset . Solution is Debug your code see if `resultLoadSelectedNews` is getting called or not with `isSuccess` as `true`.

Comment: resultLoadSelectedNews is called, i have console the value inside its correct as i expected. But the problem is urlForSharing is not replacing with new value after calling new fragment

Comment: That can only means Either ` urlForSharing = article.getMoreLink();` returning the same link OR your `Fragment` gets recreated some how .

Comment: I just confirmed it again, the value of `urlForSharing` in the  `resultLoadSelectedNews` is the update value. This value is what I need